# Where can you walk onto and touch Lynn Creek, in North Vancouver?

Tags: vancouver

[This post dated 2015/8/5](http://www.worldfortravel.com/2015/08/05/lynn-canyon-park-north-vancouver-canada/)'s 1st 2 pictures depict Lynn Canyon Suspension Bridge, whose location I already know  and that that is clearly suspended high above Lynn Creek. So please see the entitled question motivated by [this Instagram post](http://www.imgrum.net/media/1258178840687802569_3122526789):

.[image]

> Why can't all rivers be this pure? About the shot: This is at Lynn Canyon Park in Lynn Creek - shot using GoPro. You can access this area by going over the suspension bridge and heading towards the 30 foot pool. The babbling brook was so peaceful with crystal clear water. You don't get access to things like this at the Capilano Suspension Bridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous trails in the Lynn Canyon park area.  Quite a few that travel alongside the creek, some that go right to it.

http://www.lynncanyonecologycentre.ca/park_trails.html

Comment: I can attribute to that. In fact, I actually fell into the creek last year trying to take a picture.